# WCF client proxy keep alive?

Tags: wcf, proxy, client, auto-generate

It there any disadvantage of creating a wcf client in code everytime a call is needed. currently i have a static class that creates a client and reuses it for a period of time (couple of minutes before the wcf service times out)

i'm having problems with it getting into a faulted state while i'm in development because i keep recompiling the WCF code. its an annoyance now but think it'll be fine in production.

but... creating client proxy with user creds everytime a call is made... bad practice? performance issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best answer is a little of both.

there is definitely a performance hit creating a proxy client every call. if you can create a proxy client and use it for all the calls you're going to make immediately. then dispose of it. it is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no performance penalty and this is the good way of doing it i.e create a client proxy each time you need it.
And each time you're done with it, it is a recommended best practice to always close the proxy. Closing the proxy releases the connection held toward the service, which is particularly important to do in the presence of a transport session. It also helps ensure the threshold for the maximum number of connections on the client’s machine is not reached. Closing the proxy terminates the session with the service instance.